# Number of paths through 3D lattice

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking to find the number of paths through the 3-D lattice from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the point $(7,3,5)$. Each step made can only move forwards 1 unit in the x,y or z direction.

I think the answer is (number of paths from $(0,0,0)$ to $(7,3,4)$) + (number of paths from $(0,0,0)$ to $(7,2,5)$) + (number of paths from $(0,0,0)$ to $(6,3,5)$) but I don't know how to calculate the three individual components of the sum. Am I supposed to use the multinomial formula $\binom{k+m+n}{k,m,n}=\frac{(k+m+n)!}{k!m!n!}\;$ for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paths are in bijection with words of length $15$ over the alphabet $\{x, y ,z\}$ with exactly $7$ letters as $x$, $3$ letters as $y$ and $5$ letters as $z$. Here $x$ represents a $(1,0,0)$ step, $y$ represents a $(0,1,0)$ step and $z$ represents a $(0,0,1)$ step. Hence the number of ways is
$$
\binom{15}{7, 3, 5}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got the same answer with your method and my longer one.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer should be correct: This follows from the logic of counting paths in $2$ dimensions:

There is $1$ to get to $(0, 0)$. There are therefore $n$ ways to get to $(0, n)$ or $(n, 0)$. Any place with positive coordinates $(a, b)$ has the sum of the ways to get to $(a-1, b)$ and $(a, b-1)$.

You may recognize this pattern of construction as the same as Pascal's triangle. Thus, the number of ways to $(a, b)$ is ${a+b}\choose a$.

Thus, a similar construction method in $3$ dimensions will yield [Pascal's Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid). Hence, your calculation is correct as any point in Pascal's pyramid is $\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!\cdot b!\cdot c!}.$